# Is there a way to know if phone have an active call?

Tags: android, telephonymanager

I already tried `TelephonyManager`, `PhoneStateListener`. What I need is a method will return the current state of the phone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you used `TelephonyManager` & `PhoneStateListener`.

Then you need to [LISTEN_CALL_FORWARDING_INDICATOR](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneStateListener.html#LISTEN_CALL_FORWARDING_INDICATOR).

e.g:

- [`onCallForwardingIndicatorChanged (boolean cfi)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneStateListener.html#onCallForwardingIndicatorChanged(boolean))
- [`onCallStateChanged (int state,  String incomingNumber)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneStateListener.html#onCallStateChanged(int,%20java.lang.String))
  onClallStateChanged take first param state with integer values e.g :

1- [CALL_STATE_IDLE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#CALL_STATE_IDLE) with value **0** and that's mean Device call state: No activity.

2- OR [CALL_STATE_RINGING](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#CALL_STATE_RINGING) with value **1** and that's mean Device call state: Ringing. A new call arrived and is ringing or waiting. In the latter case, another call is already active.

3- [CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK) and that's mean Device call state: Off-hook. At least one call exists that is dialing, active, or on hold, and no calls are ringing or waiting.

You may need to use [READ_PHONE_STATE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#READ_PHONE_STATE) Permissions.